# Finding a license that prohibits distribution

Tags: license-recommendation, distribution

I have some open-source things I’ve made, and I am trying to get a license that prohibits the redistribution of them. By this, I mean when I publish it to wherever I do, I don’t want to permit others to download my software and publish it on their own website, without crediting me or putting my links. They are Minecraft function packs and maps which can be accessed easily, and I publish them onto a site with my own download link. Some people download these projects and put them up on their own site, without permission, removing all credit, changing the link, and sometimes they copy the description I have.

I’ve been looking on https://choosealicense.com/, but no license there fits what I’m looking for.

Comment: Are you happy with redistribution if you are credited? (If not, then what you are looking for is not an open-source license as defined by this site).

Comment: No license in the world will stop people doing that, if they cannot or don't want to obey simple rules like "give credit". A no-distribution rule (which will then NOT be open source) also then won't stop them from distributing it. Such problems are dealt with by courts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not be a free license.

However, you can choose the GNU GPL which will allow redistribution, but it has to stay open source.